# File upload create a file in /tmp

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework

When using a form that uploads a file to my Play! Framework application, a file is created in `${application_path}/tmp/` with an unique ID like :

```
0851e44f-8d7e-4afd-8edf-3d9bd6c909c9
```

and contains all the data sended by the form (POST & FILES)

I located the creation of this file in :

```
play.server.StreamChunkAggregator.java:51
```

But I don't know why this file is not removed when the request is finished.
Is there any reason that the file isn't removed? is it specific to Play (1.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be removed automatically at the end of the request, so something unusual must be going wrong.

Comment: Ok, that's was what I expected. I think after moving from IcedTea to the real Java JVM, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the classical way of Server API to manage upload files?
Why they are not deleted ? I don't know but I see the same kind of behavior in Tomcat...

Comment: Do you know if these files are kept indefinitely or not? because it could quickly take a lot of Gb if there is many file uploads right?

Comment: Apparently, in Tomcat, I read that they should be cleared at restart but I never verified so I'm not sure about it!